# how to use negative numbers as one in assembly?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have a arithmetic program in assembly, but when i add, subtract, multiply negative numbers, it will not result in desired output.

For Example

input:

```
-1+2=66675 (should be 1)

-1-1=656745 (should be -2)

-1*-1=66757 (should be 1)
```

**Questions:**

- how would i treat (-) and (1) as one?
- how to do arithmetic operation in signed numbers?

any advice please ...

Comment: In CONVERT RESULT TO ASCII: MOV AL , BYTE PTR RESULT + 1 ;AT FIRST CHECK IF AX IS POSITIVE OR NEGETIVE... If you find that the number is negative you should convert it to twos compliment. Then when you are converting it to human readable text you will need to convert it back.

Comment: ok now i know thanks for your time.il keep in mind everything that ive learned from you.God Bless! :)

Comment: Yup have a great day man.  Wish I could be more helpful but ASM is far from my native language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading up on 2's compliment and the difference between signed and unsigned ints. The value you are showing looks suspiciously like a signed int negative value being translated into an unsigned int value without doing a conversion. Negative ints have a Most Significant Bit that is set to 1.  If you shove that value into an unsigned int without first masking then you get a much larger number then expected.

Example in a 8 bit representation:

```
signed value = -1 
unsigned value = 255 
binary = 1111 1111

Take the twos compliment: 
       1111 1111
XOR    0000 0000
equals 0000 0000
add1   0000 0001
dec value = 1
```

You can learn more here (They have an example for two's compliment addition you can look at): http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/2s_comp.htm

Comment: so u mean if i input (-1+2), then -1 should be converted first into 2's compliment in order for it to be treated as -1? please bear with me, i am very new to assembly..and we have a calculator proj without discussing us the assembly language..i really have a hard time understanding this one ...

Comment: An 8 bit (yours is larger but 8 bits is an easier example) unsigned int has a value range of 0 to 255.  A signed 8 bit int is -128 to 127.  Twos compliment is the scheme used to make an addition operation work.  ASM is very low level and depending on the environment you may not have a signed int. Your print function is saying I have 1111 1111 so my number must be 255 when really its -1.

Comment: The key is to treat all numbers that start with ^1^000 0000 as a negative number that has been converted with twos compliment.  In my example if you try to add 200 to the value it will muck everything up because you are adding a positive number that's too big for the container!

Comment: ok i got your point...if it's typical only math problem, it would be easy for me to perform the process but im having problems when it comes to implement this to assembly..i already have a program of calculator but the functions are lacking.e.g. cannot perform negative numbers and i also have problems in division *sigh* ..well anyways, thanks for the very useful information ..

Comment: But you can! (two's compliment -1) 1111 1111 + (2) 0000 0010 = (one) 0000 0001. (twos compliment -4) 1111 1100 * (4) 0000 0100 = (twos compliment -16) 1111 0000. Just make sure you store negative numbers as it's two's compliment value and make sure that no positive number exceeds the new range, which is about half what it was before. It just takes some practice to get it down.  That same site has good info on how to do binary addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: can i ask another one?how can i treat (-) and (1) together as one?should i keep them in same memory?because after i type the (-) then another process for another char (1) , where should i meet them to perform as one?

Comment: I think what you are asking is... In my visual display I enter the "-" char then the "1", "5" and "5" chars respectively.  How do I treat it as the dec number -155?  I'm not an expert on best practices for this but my first approach would be to check for the "-" char then make an atoi function for the rest of the input.  If the "-" char was there I would translate it with two's compliment then enter it in memory. if not just enter the atoi value in memory. Don't forget to check if these numbers are too big.  Don't get bogged down, these are hard ideas for everyone to understand at first.

Comment: for clear understanding about what i am trying to say or do, can i post the code here?after you see the program, ca u tell me if it's possible for me to do everything what you've been said without changing the whole program, anyways it has a lot of comments, it's easy for you to track down.just see my program if it's ok for you?

Comment: I don't think I would be the best person for that.  It's been almost 4 years since I've touched ASM ;)  I had to solve similar problems in academia to get my degree but I haven't worked in that low of a level since.

Comment: ok i understand, maybe i could post parts of my code , only the processes after getting the inputs, and you could just tell me what parts of the program should i modify?il post the code above together with my post.

Comment: i've updated my post above..i hope you could help me even just to pin point the areas where i should modify to perform negative arithmetic.